# Solving a Boundary Value Problem with parameter delta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following:

y'' - y'/$\delta$ = -2/$\delta$

y(0) = 0, y(1) = 0

for:
0 < x < 1

To be solved for y(x) in terms of $\delta$

I am running in circles.

Comment: any constraints on $\delta$?

Comment: Yes, I apologize. It's where  δ << 1, e.g., 0.01, 0.001, etc.

Comment: $0 < \delta << 1$? or $0 \leq \delta << 1$? (it's a stupid question... =D)

Comment: It's 0 < δ << 1

Comment: In general, I know I am meant to compute this by computing a complimentary solution (yc) and then a particular solution (yp), with y(x) = yc + yp.

Comment: And what's the problem with that? is it the discussion with delta?

Comment: In doing so, I can only find a trivial solution. I suspect I might be making an error.

Answer (score 0):

For the $y_g(t)$ you need to solve $$y'' - \frac{y'}{\delta} = 0$$ the related characteristic polynomial is
$$\lambda^2 - \frac{\lambda}{\delta} = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda \left( \lambda - \frac{1}{\delta} \right) = 0.$$

Hence

$$y_g(t) = C_1 + C_2 e^{\frac{1}{\delta}t}$$

For the particular solution, since $-\frac{2}{\delta}$ is a constant you can use as a particular solution a polynomial $y_p(t) = at^2 + bt$, putting this into the original equation you will end up with:

$$2a - \frac{2at + b}{\delta} = \frac{-2}{\delta} \Rightarrow  -\frac{2 a}{\delta} t + 2a - \frac{b}{\delta} + \frac{2}{\delta} = 0$$

where $a = 0$ while ...

$$\frac{b}{\delta} + \frac{2}{\delta} = 0 \Rightarrow b = -2$$

so $y_p(t) = -2t$

and finally

$$y(t) = y_g(t) + y_p(t) = C_1 + C_2 e^{\frac{1}{\delta}t} - 2t$$

the constants are derived by posing the initial conditions and solving the linear system related.

(Assuming no error in calculus).

Anyway since $\delta$ is very small the system is instable, (and you could see that a priori by the study of characteristic of the polynomial).

Comment: Another way to solve the equation is the laplace transform.